# Range form oninput function with output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

I have an input range slider that represents a timeline(A video timeline):

```
<form oninput="amount.value=slider.value">
<output>0:00</output>
<input type="range" id="slider" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="60" value="0">                                                       

<output name="amount" id="rangevalue" for="slider">0</output>
</form>
```

Until now the timeline was presented in seconds. Now I want to change it into minutes.
Through Javascript, I have managed to change the `rangevalue.value` to any string I like- so I will be able to change the seconds to minutes. The problem is with the `oninput="amount.value=slider.value"` - What this line does is when the user changes the slider's value it automatically changes the output's value to present what time(in seconds) the slider is currently on. But now I want to change that output's value to minutes so I have tried a few approaches: (I am using "00:" just as a string example)

1. `oninput="amount.value="00:"+slider.value"` - does not work at all.
2. I have created a Javascript method:

   ```
   function sliderTimeChanged() {
   amount.value ="00:"+ slider.value;
   }
   ```

   and in the form:

   ```
   oninput="sliderTimeChanged()"
   ```

   Also doesn't work. How can I manage to control the amount.value while the user manually changes the slider's value? Thanks in advance for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach should be `oninput="amount.value='00:' + slider.value"`

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DnE/1/)

For the second approach, viewing the console window shows you that the `amount` is undefined, in fact `amount` is just the name of the second `output`. You can replace it with `rangevalue` which is the `id` of the second `output`. The reason it works for ***inline*** code, because in that context `this` (which is the implicit context) refers to the `form`, and you can access the input field in `form` by the field's `name` (hence `amount` works). While in some function, `this` refers to `window`, so you can't access a field via its `name`, instead you have to access it via `id`. Although you should use `document.getElementById` to get access to it because as far as I know accessing some element via `id` as a property of the `window` is just supported in modern browsers.

### [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DnE/2/)

Comment: Oh god, I am ashamed. Thanks very much! accepted in a few minutes. Will it also work on a JavaScript function?

Comment: @Oranges see the updated answer for more explanation.